# R CMD SHLIB Fortran 90 file which use NetCDF

Tags: r, fortran, netcdf

I would like compile a fortran 90 file which use NetCDF. I have installed [NetCDF-Fortran](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/building_netcdf_fortran.html) and as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837669/2418532), to compile the file test_nc.f90:

```
program test_nc
    use netcdf
    implicit none
    integer :: ncid, nc_err

    nc_err = nf90_open('test.nc', nf90_nowrite, ncid)
    nc_err = nf90_close(ncid)
end program test_nc
```

The compilation with gfortran is

```
gfortran test_nc.f90 -o test_nc `nf-config --fflags --flibs`
```

where `nf-config --fflags --flibs` is:

```
-I/usr/include
-L/usr/lib -lnetcdff -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -lnetcdf -lnetcdf -ldl -lz -lcurl -lm
```

Replacing program by subroutine is

```
subroutine test_nc
    use netcdf
    implicit none
    integer :: ncid, nc_err

    nc_err = nf90_open('test.nc', nf90_nowrite, ncid)
    nc_err = nf90_close(ncid)
end subroutine test_nc
```

However, When I run

```
R CMD SHLIB test_nc.f90  `nf-config --fflags --flibs`
```

results in:

```
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-k1TtL4/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c  test_nc.f90 -o test_nc.o
test_nc.f90:2:8:

    2 |     use netcdf
      |        1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘netcdf.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Also, when I try:

```
R CMD SHLIB test_nc.f90 -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -lnetcdff -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -lnetcdf -lnetcdf -ldl -lz -lcurl -lm
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-k1TtL4/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c  test_nc.f90 -o test_nc.o
```

results in:

```
test_nc.f90:2:8:

    2 |     use netcdf
      |        1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘netcdf.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:195: test_nc.o] Error 1
```

How can I tell R CMD SHLIB to use the Netcdf-fortran libraries?

?SHLIB shows

```
R CMD SHLIB -o mylib.so a.f b.f -L/opt/acml3.5.0/gnu64/lib -lacml
```

So I guess it is possible to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the call to `R CMD SHLIB` the options you have provided from `nf-config` are taken only as *linker* options.  The compilation step is failing because setting the search path for the NetCDF Fortran module is required before the link process.

To add the `-I...` option from `nf-config` you can use the environment variable `PKG_FCFLAGS`:

```sh
env PKG_FCFLAGS="`nf-config --fflags`" R CMD SHLIB test_nc.f90 `nf-config --flibs`
```

Alternatively, you can put `PKG_FCFLAGS` in your Makevars file.

(Note that, unlike C and C++, the include path option for module files is not for the pre-processing stage.)

Comment: object  test_nc.so returns Segmentation fault (core dumped). I tried with including Makevars but gives undefined symbol: __netcdf_MOD_nf90_close. According to this https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-fortran/issues/76 it is compiled with the correct flags.

Comment: If using `Makevars` then you'll still need to set the linker options to point to the library.  Did you set the linker options in `Makevars` or continue with ``nf-config --flibs`` on the command line?  Or is it the undefined symbol when you try to load the library?

Comment: And I assume the segmentation fault comes from when it did work and you tried to use the `test_nc.so` in your R session.  How did you try to call it from R?

Comment: On Makevars, If I write PKG_FCFLAGS="`nf-config --fflags --flibs`" I get "Cannot open module file ‘netcdf.mod’". When I take out "--flibs", I get "undefined symbol: __netcdf_MOD_nf90_close". As I`m trying to create an R package here, I call it with "R CMD INSTALL ." Should I need to create an confgure.ac?

Comment: `PKG_FCFLAGS` should just be the `--fflags` option, for compiler flags. The linker flags from `--flibs` must be given elsewhere, such as in the `R CMD` command.  Does the full `env ...` command I give work in your case?

Comment: Here I am testing with netcdf-fortran and R https://github.com/ibarraespinosa/nf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212747/discussion-between-sergio-and-francescalus).